# DataGridViewColumn.Index different than dataGridView.Columns["colName"].Index

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView with some columns in it. For example I have the column colService and my DatagridView is called dgvServices. Then the following values are different.

```
colService.Index
dgvServices.Columns[colService.Name].Index
```

I also checked their DisplayIndex property and it is also different. In my datagridview I have some hidden columns. Also some columns are bound to a datatable column and others not. Why are these 2 values different?

Thanks

Comment: Is colService == dgvServices.Columns[colService.Name]? And also which of the indexes is the correct one?

Comment: @Svarog Yes colService == dgvServices.Columns[colService.Name]. The correct Index for my purpose is dgvServices.Columns...

Comment: @Svarog Oops looking wrong column. Eventually they are not equal. The column is hidden and bound to a datatable.

Comment: If they are not equal, then here's your problem. Is it possible you are using both custom columns and auto-generated columns?

Comment: I understand that this is the problem. All columns are created at design time. I noticed that any columns that are bound to my datasource, express this behavior. The datasource doesn't have any column that isn't bound to datagrid. So no new columns are added to datagrid. I will try though (can't right now) to set AutoGenerateColumns to false and see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem occurred because AutoGenerateColumns property of the DGV is set to true. That way when the datasource is assigned to DGV new columns are created add override the existing ones. Setting AutoGenerateColumns to false solves the problem.

Comment: That's exactly when I said in second comment.
In case this fixes the problem, please consider thumbing-up my comment. Thanks!